# Calling a twig template depending on the number of field items

Tags: theming

I need to call different twig templates of an image field depending on the number of items of this field. If there is only 1 image item, I'd like to use template1.html.twig. If there are > 1 image items, I'd like to use template2.html.twig.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Can you use length to do conditional logic in the template? https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/length.html  In other words, one template, but you use length to count the number of items and then process it differently based on that.

Comment: I know the usage of length - this would be my solution when I know how to call different templates. I don't know the code to call 2 different templates when there is only 1 (from a module) and absolutely know file (alter) name suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a simple template suggestion added from a custom module or theme along the following snippet.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] === 'field_MYFIELD') {
    // Fallback.
    $values = '';

    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList $items */
    $items = $variables['element']['#items'];
    if ($items->count() == 1) {
      $values = '__single_image';
    }
    if ($items->count() > 1) {
      $values = '__slideshow';
    }

    $suggestions[] = 'field__' . $variables['element']['#field_name'] . $values;
  }
}
```

This would allow you to have `field--field-MYFIELD--single-image.html.twig` or `field--field-MYFIELD--slideshow.html.twig`.

Flush cache!